# How to merge a canvas created by Konva on a blob:http image so it can be sent in an email

Tags: web-applications, html5-canvas, blob, konvajs

I would really appreciate any help I could get with this. I am stoke for hours now. I am trying to do a webApp Function where people can take a selfie, then put an image over it and send it to an e-mail.
Till now I have this:

```
<img id="frame">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var camera = document.getElementById('camera');
    var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
    camera.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // Do something with the image file.
        frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        alert(frame.src);
    });
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    function drawImage(imageObj) {
        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
        });
        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
            image: imageObj,
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
            width: 200,
            height: 137,
            draggable: true
        });
        // add cursor styling
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseover', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseout', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });
        layer.add(darthVaderImg);
        stage.add(layer);
    }
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'kochmuetze.png';
</script>
```

It takes the picture and I can drag the *kochmuetze.png* on the image. But how to I save the combination to one image?

Comment: For me the question is unclear. You can user stage.toDataURL() to convert it to base64 image.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is unclear let me explane it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if it is unclear. I am taking a picture on a mobile device. And then save it on the site with this function:

```
  <img id="frame">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var camera = document.getElementById('camera');
    var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
    camera.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // Do something with the image file.
        frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        alert(frame.src);
    });
</script>
```

Then, because i did not find another solution I am using Konva to enable the user to position another image on top of that picture (selfie). I do that with this function:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    function drawImage(imageObj) {
        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
        });
        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
            image: imageObj,
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
            width: 200,
            height: 137,
            draggable: true
        });
        // add cursor styling
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseover', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseout', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });
        layer.add(darthVaderImg);
        stage.add(layer);
    }
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'kochmuetze.png';
</script>
```

And now what I would like to be able to do is. Make a function for an on click event that enables the user to send the complete image composition via email. So I need to merge the selfie that the user made via the konva layer, and then save the image so I will be able to send it thrue php mailer or so.